# How to delay the alert so it only fires when there's an n seconds left on the candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I usually trade on the 5m or 15m timeframes, and often time the alert fires too early when the candle first forming ... toward the end of it, the conditions of the signals are no longer true. For example, at the beginning of the candle, it was crossing up into the RSI overbought, but at the end of the candle it doesn't touch the level.

So is there any way to set an alert so that it only check the conditions and fire only when the conditions are met when the candle has 30 seconds left to run? Or 60 seconds ?

Thank you so much.

I tried

```
num = input(20, "Seconds Left for signals", tooltip="Always set alerts with 'once per bar' to  trigger with this buffer")

sec_left = barstate.isrealtime ? (time_close - timenow) / 1000 : 0

num < sec_left
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Since pine script codes run when the candle is closing, you have to adjust your time frame based on that. For example if you want to check 1 min before closing the 5 min candle so you must run the code on a 1 min chart (properly adjust RSI length to it or use the RSI of 5 min with the same length by `request.security()`) and check that `minutes % 5 == 1`. If you want to check it at 30 sec earlier so you should go the 30 sec time frame.

You can also set an open ended alert on RSI for that purpose if there is not more thing to do in the script...